# all support libraries same version

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

i'm trying to add play services to my app in the gralde dependicies. Now i see it gives an error of using the same library level. I don't see how to solve this. I've searched on google and can't find anything. Here is my gradle module file:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bnf.xpclicker"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:2.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:7.4.0''
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error? also please make sure you have setup maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } on your top-level build.gradle

Comment: Do you use any others libraries? This happens when you use other library(containing support libs) not the same version with current version `27.1.1`.

Comment: @Aydin Does this question still need an answer?